# Spotless + Eclipse Formatter + Java 17 = Error on String Literals + Removing Unused Imports

Tags: java, maven, java-17, spotless, spotless-maven-plugin

I am upgrading my Spring Boot app to use Spring 3+ and Java 17. However, I'm now getting an error when trying to apply spotless and to do with `removeUnusedImports` feature.

This issue is similar to what has been reported here:
[github.com/diffplug/spotless/issues/923](https://github.com/diffplug/spotless/issues/923)

I have tried a few things, such as adding this:

```
-Xmx4096m
--add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.file=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.parser=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.util=ALL-UNNAMED
```

To my IntelliJ VM Options as per here: https://github.com/google/google-java-format#intellij-jre-config

I also tried to add this directly to maven through typing the below on my git terminal:

```
export MAVEN_OPTS="-Xmx4096m --add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.ap
i=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code=ALL-UNNAMED --
add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.file=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=jdk.
compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.parser=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.s
un.tools.javac.tree=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.u
$ git config --global credential.helper "cache --timeout=3600"
```

However, the issue still persists.

```
  <spotless-plugin.version>2.34.0</spotless-plugin.version>
  <spotless-eclipse.version>4.18.0</spotless-eclipse.version>
  <spring-boot.version>3.1.3</spring-boot.version>
```

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.diffplug.spotless</groupId>
                <artifactId>spotless-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${spotless-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <formats>
                        <!-- you can define as many formats as you want, each is independent -->
                        <format>
                            <!-- define the files to apply to -->
                            <includes>
                                <include>*.java</include>
                                <include>*.md</include>
                            </includes>
                            <!-- define the steps to apply to those files -->
                            <trimTrailingWhitespace/>
                            <endWithNewline/>
                            <indent>
                                <tabs>true</tabs>
                                <spacesPerTab>4</spacesPerTab>
                            </indent>
                        </format>
                    </formats>
                    <!-- define a language-specific format -->
                    <java>
                        <!-- no need to specify files, inferred automatically, but you can if you want -->

                         <removeUnusedImports/> <!-- self-explanatory -->

                        <!-- apply a specific flavor of google-java-format and reflow long strings -->
                        <eclipse>
                            <version>${spotless-eclipse.version}</version> <!-- optional -->
                            <file>${project.basedir}/eclipse-formatter.xml</file> <!-- optional -->
                        </eclipse>
                    </java>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

This is the exact error here:

```
[INFO] Spotless.Format is keeping 1 files clean - 0 were changed to be clean, 1 were already clean, 0 were skipped because caching determined they were already clean
[ERROR] Step 'removeUnusedImports' found problem in 'src\test\java\com\myproject\amlar\client\DBClient.java':
null
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at com.diffplug.spotless.java.GoogleJavaFormatStep$State.lambda$constructRemoveUnusedFunction$4 (GoogleJavaFormatStep.java:211)
Caused by: com.google.googlejavaformat.java.FormatterException: 37:25: error: unclosed string literal
    at com.google.googlejavaformat.java.FormatterException.fromJavacDiagnostics (FormatterException.java:51)
    at com.google.googlejavaformat.java.RemoveUnusedImports.parse (RemoveUnusedImports.java:262)
    at com.google.googlejavaformat.java.RemoveUnusedImports.removeUnusedImports (RemoveUnusedImports.java:219)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at com.diffplug.spotless.java.GoogleJavaFormatStep$State.lambda$constructRemoveUnusedFunction$4 (GoogleJavaFormatStep.java:211)
    at com.diffplug.spotless.java.GoogleJavaFormatStep$State.lambda$createRemoveUnusedImportsOnly$2 (GoogleJavaFormatStep.java:188)
    at com.diffplug.spotless.FormatterFunc.apply (FormatterFunc.java:32)
    at com.diffplug.spotless.FormatterStepImpl$Standard.format (FormatterStepImpl.java:82)
    at com.diffplug.spotless.FormatterStep$Strict.format (FormatterStep.java:88)
    at com.diffplug.spotless.Formatter.compute (Formatter.java:246)
    at com.diffplug.spotless.PaddedCell.calculateDirtyState (PaddedCell.java:203)
    at com.diffplug.spotless.PaddedCell.calculateDirtyState (PaddedCell.java:190)
    at com.diffplug.spotless.maven.SpotlessApplyMojo.process (SpotlessApplyMojo.java:48)
    at com.diffplug.spotless.maven.AbstractSpotlessMojo.execute (AbstractSpotlessMojo.java:225)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  2.439 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-09-18T12:43:17+01:00
```

Thank you.

Comment: UnclosedStringLiteral -> hasn't got much to do with import statements. Have you checked your DBClient.java class?

Comment: Can you add a [mcve] containing the smallest amount of code needed to reproduce this problem?

Comment: There are some people who have already reported this error https://github.com/diffplug/spotless/issues/923

Comment: The string literals is to do with the new features from Java 17, and the error only happens when the tag for `removeUsusedImports` is enabled.

Comment: Ok. Disable `removeUsusedImports` until the issue is resolved. What other answer did you expect?

Comment: so disable that, and check the code of the class where you get the problem

Comment: I've disabled it already, but I would still like to use the functionality of removing the unused imports.

Comment: The docs seem to be suggesting workaround solutions for the google formatter, and I tried then all,  however, for some reason it's not working for the eclipse formatter, reason why I posted the question here.

Comment: "use the functionality of using the unused imports" .... ok ... what? what exactly do you mean?

Comment: The linked github issue suggests there is a bug. All software has bugs. This one seems odd, why aren't you removing unused imports before you commit your code? That seems like a pre-commit check to me. Or something to catch in code review.

Comment: Humans can make mistake and forget to remove the imports, reason why trying to automate the process. But the main point is of the question is that this was working before, and is not anymore, and perhaps someone has found a workaround for it and can provide some assistance.

Comment: The authors themselves call it a bug, meaning it doesn't work (as should). Nowadays all decent IDE's provide a somewhat automatic way to 'clean up (unused) imports', so this is a nice-to-have (at best). Meaning, especially if it doesn't work, it's pointless. The main risk of having unused imports is that you're using resources you don't need to use by loading classes you are not going to use, unless you're really outdoing yourself there, it's not a major issue. As Elliott said, it remains good practice to check yourself before committing code. Takes hardly any time and solves all your issues.

Comment: This is probably more the problem mentioned at [Step remove unused import break on multiline string](https://github.com/diffplug/spotless/issues/681)  and the fix would be to upgrade the spotless-plugin.version to 2.36.0 or later (https://github.com/diffplug/spotless/issues/681#issuecomment-1498452643)

Comment: I tried updating spotless before raising the question, but got this other error, which happens even without the removeUnusedImports tag, so I kept the older version: [ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.diffplug.spotless:spotless-maven-plugin:2.36.0:apply (default-cli) on project aml-ar-api-automation: Execution default-cli of goal com.diffplug.spotl
ess:spotless-maven-plugin:2.36.0:apply failed.: NullPointerException -> [Help 1]